# How do I install Chrome in my device, an Acer r11 chromebook

Tags: xubuntu, acer, chromebook

I just picked up this device (Acer r11 Chromebook) a couple days ago. I installed Linux just fine using crouton (unity so xubuntu?) I have been trying to browse the web, specifically Udemy.com and Google Docs, as I got the rig to teach myself SQL and Data Querying. The Linux install went fine... except there are a couple problems that are preventing me from continuing:

1) When I use the NerSurf Web Browser, the app doesn't display Web pages correctly. Including this site, Ask Ubuntu and Udemy.com, I haven't tried Google docs yet but I imagine that would be even worse. Maybe there is a fix so I can still use NetSurf?

2) I am unable to download and install the proper version of another web browser, chrome.

I installed Linux from developer mode using the command: [sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -e -t unity] or something very close to that, after downloading the crouton file. I am posting this from my phone since the NetSurf app cannot display the human verification page correctly when I post this question from my Acer in the NetSurf app... pretty frustrating.

I have the file-roller app and even downloaded the chrome-linux.zip and extracted it... not sure how to install it from there. I ran the command wget dl.google.......stable_current_1386.deb as this one YouTube video demonstrated. The terminal then returned

Resolving dl.google.......
Connecting to dl.google........ connected
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-07-31 08:51:41 ERROR 404 : Not Found.

The ... was actually text. The ........ represent where I shortened the output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a beginner with Linux but I do have limited experience with C++ and Python. Thanks

Comment: It's saying the file you tried to download is not working in the way you want it to. Try running this command from the terminal `sudo apt install chromium-browser`. Once it is complete, look for chromium (the open source version of Google Chrome) in your menu. At the very least, it is functional and will get you a browser that works for downloads and displaying websites.

Comment: Ok, do you know what command I should use?

Comment: @Bitz The command is in their comment. And there's nothing preventing you from downloading Chrome's .deb file and install that (your Ubuntu should be 64-bit). At least Firefox is also available in the repositories and other can be easily installed as well.

Comment: Thatguy updated his comment actually. Before he just said the first line. His post worked wonders for me. Just ran chromium the first time. How do I mark the comment left by Thatguy as the answer? Thanks a bunch btw

Comment: @michaelbay makes a good point. Firefox is also available. I just made an assumption that you'd prefer chrome/chromium. There's no need to mark mine as the answer, just answer your own question with the steps you took to rectify the problem. Mark your answer as accepted, and you'll even get a badge for it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Answer: I installed Chromium using the Terminal command:

`sudo apt install chromium-browser`

Using the Chromium browser has none of the issues I was experiencing while using the NetSurf browser.

You guys are helpful and responsive. Keep it up.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. You can say something along this lines: "I ended up installing Chromium with ... command..."